# Kio estas la vera signifo de "muĝi"?

Tags: word-meaning, history, meaning, akademia-vortaro, fundamento

[Laŭ PIV](http://vortaro.net/#mu%C4%9Di), «muĝi» signifas:

> **1.** Bleki, kiel bovo.
>
> **2.** (figurasence) Aŭdigi fortan, obtuzan, longe tiratan sonon: *muĝanta popolamaso*.

Ŝajnas do, ke «bleki kiel bovo» estas la precipa signifo, ĉu ne? Tamen kiam me serĉas en la *Tekstaro*, mi trovis entute 110 uzojn de la verbo «muĝi», el kiuj nur ses (6) estas por bovoj… Mi do serĉis en aliaj vortaroj.

[En la *Esperanto-English Dictionary*](https://archive.org/stream/esperantoenglish00mottrich#page/96/mode/2up) fare de A. Motteau (3-a eldono, 1907), kiu estas *aprobita de D-o Zamenhof* laŭ la kovrilo, jen la difino, kiun mi trovis (paĝo 96):

> **muĝ**-*i*, to roar (wind, waves, etc.).

[Laŭ la Webster de 1913](http://www.websters1913.com/words/Roar), tio respondas al tiu difino:

> **2.** To make a loud, confused sound, as winds, waves, passing vehicles, a crowd of persons when shouting together, or the like.

Kie estas la bovoj?

En la *Dictionnaire Esperanto-Français* de Louis de Beaufront (1904), oni trovas la saman difinon (paĝo 115):

> **muĝ**, mugir (le vent, la tempête, les flots).

Denove, oni diras, ke «muĝi» devas uziĝi nur pri la vento, la ŝtormo kaj la maro. Kie estas la bovoj?

La *Fundamento de Esperanto* (1905) donas difinojn tre malklarajn por «muĝ» (paĝo 140). Por la franca, ĝi tradukiĝas per «mugir». Nu, «mugir» estas [tre vasta vorto](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mugir), kiu povas uziĝi tiel bone pri bovoj, kiel pri hipopotamoj, panteroj, leonoj, kaj… eĉ torentoj, orgenoj, ktp.

Sed ĉu hipopotamoj, panteroj kaj leonoj blekas kiel bovoj?

Finfine la [Akademia Vortaro](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademia_vortaro/index.html?serchas=1&ajakso=0&hazardo=&tt=1490208890&ve=mu%C4%9D&vg=-&vr=jes&vp=jes&vs=jes&vm=jes&vl=jes&vf=jes&vk=jes&va=1&tradukofr=1&tradukoen=1&tradukode=1&tradukopl=1&tradukoru=1#avtitolo) donas al «muĝ» la sekvaj tradukoj:

- France: mugir
- Angle: roar (wind, etc.)
- Germane: brausen, brüllen
- Pole: huczeć, ryczeć
- Ruse: шипѣть

Nu! Mi scias nur la francan kaj la anglan, sed laŭ mia serĉado en la interreto «шипѣть» (kiu nun skribiĝas *шипеть*) havas nenian rilaton kun bovoj…

Tio, kio plej mirigas min, estas, ke «muĝi» uziĝas pli ofte pri *leonoj* ol pri *bovoj* (13 fojoj kontraŭ 6) en la [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/). Ĉu tio signifas, ke la leonoj blekas kiel bovoj? Mi memoras neniam aŭdi leonon fari similan sonon…

Do mia mallonga demando estas, ĉu la vorto «muĝi» havas klaran difinon? Aŭ ĉu ĝi estas vorto, kiun ĉiuj uzas kun la signifo, kiun ni volas? Kial ĝi nuntempe uziĝas tiom forte pri bovoj, sed ne pri leonoj, eĉ se la literaturo Esperanta subtenas la leonojn pli ol la bovoj?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estas konate, ke bestoblekoj estas inter la malplej internaciigeblaj vortoj. Ili produktas metaforojn, kiuj sonas absurdaj trans lingvaj limoj.

Mi scias, ke en la angla oni diras, ke vento blekas kiel leono *(roars)*, kaj mi diras tion se mi parolas angle, sed mia plejprofundo restas konvinkita, ke vento blekas kiel bovo, kiel en la malnovaj fabeloj en mia denaska itala.

Do, se en Esperanto ni havas unusolan verbon por la blekoj de leono kaj bovo, kaj ja ankaŭ de vento, mi vidas neniun problemon. Mi eĉ dirus, ke tiel vaste difinita signifo-spaco devas enteni ankaŭ la blekon de cervo. Kaj fakte, tiel estas, kiel konfirmas [tiu ĉi paĝo](http://bulteno.esperanto-usa.org/2014/2/60-bestosonoj.html)...
(Kaj konstatu, ke tiun paĝon verkis usonanoj, kiuj opiniis neakceptebla la fakton, ke leono muĝas, do ili skribis ***roras...*** sed la Tekstaro atestas kontraŭe.)

Estas ankaŭ nesurprize, ke ***muĝi*** entenas la bruojn de maraj ondoj kaj homamasoj, ĉu koleraj (en la itala, kiel bovo), ĉu *tre* koleraj (en la itala, kiel leono)...

> ĉu la vorto «muĝi» havas klaran difinon?

**Jes,** ***muĝi*** havas klaran signifon, difinitan komence de Z kaj poste de la lingva tradicio. En la aro de eblaj bruoj ĝi reprezentas sub-aron koheran, eĉ se pli vastan ol tiu de la vortoj de la de vi konataj lingvoj.

Serĉante en la Tekstaro oni vidas, kiuj estas la limoj de tiu subaro. Tion vi jam faris, do vi devas nur alkutimiĝi al la ideo, ke Esperanto povas bonege pluvivi sen la distingoj de aliaj lingvoj. Oni ja povas distingi per adjektoj, pliklarigoj, frazturnoj... oni ne nepre faru tion per malsamaj radikoj.

> Sed ĉu hipopotamoj, panteroj kaj leonoj blekas kiel bovoj?

Kompreneble **ne,** sed ĉiu ekzistanta vorto de ĉiu ekzistanta lingvo entenas en sia signifo multajn malsamajn aferojn. Do, en Esperanto, ĉiuj tiuj bestoj malsame ***muĝas.*** Parto de la fascino de ligvolernado fontas el la malkovro, kiujn aferojn kiu lingvo metis en kiun sakon...

La alternativo estus inventi vorton por la bleko de ĉiu unuopa besto en la mondo, ĉar, estu certa, kiel ajn oni klasifikas la blekojn, ekzistas lingvo, kiu distingas inter du bestoj, kiujn vi klasifikis kune. Jam la vortoj listigitaj en la supre alligita paĝo laŭ mia gusto estas iom tro multaj: ĉu vi volas ilin ankoraŭ pliigi?

En la tekstaro oni trovas la frazon *lokomotivoj sur la surbordo siblas, muĝas kaj fajfas,* kiu estas bona ekzemplo de tri distingendaj verboj: ***fajfi*** diferencas de la aliaj du per tio, ke ĝi entenas, tipe, *belsonecon:* merlo, najtingalo, belkantaj birdoj ***fajfas.*** Ankaŭ lokomotivoj ***fajfas,*** signalcele, eble malpli bele, sed ĉiam pli bele ol tiel, kiel ili ***muĝas*** kaj ***siblas*** en sia funkciado. Ĉi tie oni havas diferencon de tonalto: ***muĝado*** estas pli profunda, ***siblado*** pli akuta.

Ĉar lokomotivo muĝas pro forbloviĝanta vaporo, anstataŭ ***muĝi*** oni povus ĉikaze uzi ***ŝuŝi:*** ĉi-lasta verbo, kiel klarigas PIV, tipe reprezentas la bruon de “gaso eliranta sub forta premo el mallarĝa tubo”. Ne ĉiuj muĝoj estas ŝuŝoj (ekzemple muĝo de leono ne), sed ankaŭ ne ĉiuj ŝuŝoj estas muĝoj: ili povas esti tiel akutaj, ke ili estas ***sibloj.*** Jen ekzemplo de verboj, kies signifaroj havas komunaĵon, sed ne samas.

En tiu signifo-spaco situas ankaŭ la rusa шипеть, kies signifon mi kontrolis [en unulingva vortaro.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x&lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x) Ĝi estas baze “soni kiel litero **ŝ**”, do kaj *sibli* kaj *ŝuŝi* kaj multaj aliaj verboj. En tiu vortaro estas interesaj ekzemploj de шипеть-antoj, laŭ ordo: *serpentoj, ansero, grasaĵo en varmega pato, akvo en krano, ĉampano, samovaro, radioricevilo.* Nu, mi diris, ke blekoj kaj bruoj estas tre malfacile internaciigeblaj... Ĉiuokaze, eĉ se **ветер шипит,** *la vento muĝas,* **estas tre malfacile trovi muĝanton, kiu povas senprobleme funkcii kun ĉiuj verboj de la UV en la respektivaj lingvoj.**

Tamen, kiel ĉe multaj vortoj, la signifo evoluis. Franclingvaj vortaristoj kiel Grosjean-Maupin kaj Waringhien vidis, ke la radiko estis francaspekta kaj fiksis france orientitan, bovo-bazitan signifon, kiun oni trovas en la Plena Vortaro de 1933 kaj kiun lernis la lingvanaro. La Tekstaro montras, kiel la vorto estis kaj estas uzata.

Comment: Dankon pro la respondo. Tamen, vi ne menciis la rusan Fundamentan tradukon de **muĝi**, *шипеть*, kiu signifas «sibli» laŭ la rusparolantoj, kiuj respondis al mi en Telegram, aŭ kiu signifas «ŝuŝi» [laŭ la Reta Vortaro…](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sxusx.html#sxusx.0i) Certe la lasta vorto pli taŭgas, ĉar oni trovas tiun frazon en la Tekstaro: *lokomotivoj sur la surbordo siblas, muĝas kaj fajfas*. Ĉu **muĝi** estas sinonimo de **ŝuŝi** en tiu frazo?

Ho! kaj vi skribis, ke hipopotamoj, panteroj kaj leonoj ne blekas kiel bovoj. Sed ĉu ili muĝas?

Comment: @maliktunga Dankon pro via komento. Sekve de ĝi mi signife plilongigis mian respondon.

Comment: Estas interese, ke la granda estimata esperanto-rusa vortaro de Boris Kondratjev (rueo.ru) tute ne enhavas signifon _"шипеть"_ (_"sibli"_) por la vorto. Laŭ ĝi,  _"muĝi"_ (_"реветь"_, _"мычать"_) esprimas ĝuste sonojn de bovo, ŝtormo, akvofalo, homamaso ktp.

Comment: Dankegon por tiu komento! Mi vidis, ke vi aldonis ĝin kiel respondon, do mi ne aldonos ĝin al la mia, kiu jam estas tre longa.

Answer (score 5):

”Kial ĝi nuntempe uziĝas tiel forte pri bovoj”: Tion kaŭzis tre verŝajne (!) la popularega Jutubaĵo ”[Dek Bovinoj](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh9w7QpyQtY)”. Kiam mi unuafoje aŭskultis la kanton lastjare, mi fakte ŝokiĝis, ĉar *mi* ĉiam kredis ke muĝas *leonoj kaj tigroj*, dum blekas ekz-e gebovoj (ĉevaloj henas). Do, ”10 Bovinoj” por mi eksonis tute absurde, kvazaŭ tiuj taŭrinoj leone bruus! :-D
***Ĉu jen vera ekzemplo de dialekta diverseco ene de Esperanto?***

La asocion inter grandaj rabobestoj kaj ”muĝi” mi ĉerpis ŝajne el la literaturaĵoj, kiujn mi legis, interalie la jena poemo de [Lu Jixin](http://miiraslimake.over-blog.com/tag/esperanto/):

> ENKAĜITA TIGRO :
>
> Kaĝe
>
> Kaĝe
>
> muĝas ĝi sovaĝe
>
> kor' neniam pigra
>
> dignas kapo tigra
>
> grati
>
> grati
>
> por al mont' paradi

Comment: Ne ekzistas dubo, ke se diverslandaj esperantistoj ne parolus konstante inter si, ĝuste en tiu ĉi tereno la lingvo rapide disdialektiĝus. +1 pro la bela, oportuna citaĵo el Ĉinio.

Comment: Ankaŭ mi konis _muĝi_ precipe el alia kunteksto, kaj ĝia priskribo de la malforta "mu" en la kanto ŝajnis al mia jam preskaŭ ironia. Sed pri ti certe ankaŭ kulpas, ke en la hodiaŭa germana, mia denaska lingvo, estas du vortoj por la blekado de leonoj kaj bovoj.

Comment: Eble pro la kanto nun okazadas asociiĝo inter la du iom samsonaj vortoj ”mu” kaj ”muĝi”? Kiel Lu Jixin mi ĉiam komprenis muĝadon kiel sovaĝan, fortan. Katoj miaŭas, tigroj muĝas… Do, se la ĝenerala kompreno estas ke eĉ trankvilaj bovinoj muĝas – mi havas novan demandon: Ĉu muĝas kaj leono kaj muso? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Mi volas aldoni kelkajn, ni diru, etimologiajn konsiderojn al tiu interesa kaj malfacila demando.
Laŭ la Akademia Vortaro, kiel jam dirite, estas la jenaj tradukoj (kun aldono de la signifokampo):

- France: mugir (bruto, vento)
- Angle: roar (rabobestoj, bruto, vento)
- Germane: brausen, brüllen (maro, vento, bruto)
- Ruse: шипeть (kato, serpento: efektive la vorto signifas "sibli, ŝuŝi, kraĉospiri")
- Pole: huczeć, ryczeć (maro, vento, pafilego, bruto)

Do, komunaĵo inter ili estas, kiel skribas PIV, la malalta, brua sono, kaj tio povas koncerni kaj bestojn kaj veteron. Pripensu ankaŭ, ke bovoj ne vere muĝas per tia mallaŭta, mallonga 'mu', kiel ni diras al infanoj; male ili vere laŭte kaj longa blekas, sufiĉe komparebla al ekz. leonoj, kvankam la kvalito estas kompreneble alia.
Tio estas jam la versio kun Akademiaj Korektoj, la Universala Vortaro origine havis tion:

- France: mugir (bruto, vento)
- Angle: rush (tio estas fakte "hasti")
- Germane: brausen, zischen (maro, vento, serpento)
- Ruse: шипeть (kato, serpento: efektive la vorto signifas "sibli, ŝuŝi, kraĉospiri")
- Pole: burzyć się, wrzeć (tio estas fakte "bol(eg)i, ondadi", do forta moviĝo de akvo)

La signifoj ne estas kunigeblaj, pro kio Akademiaj korektoj estis necesaj.
Tamen oni devas konsideri, ke Z nur mezbone regis la francan kaj apenaŭ la anglan, dum la rusa estis lia gepatra, la pola lia ĉiutaga kaj la germana lia plej forta fremda lingvoj. Kaj tiujn tri lingvojn oni povas efektive signife kunigi, nome tiel, ke en ili komuna estas la elemento de sibla aŭ ŝuŝa sono, kian eligas serpentoj aŭ io pro gasa premo.*
Kaj efektive Z uzis *muĝi* laŭ la atestoj en la Tekstaro nur en tiu signifo, do ne por nomi ian obtuzan sonon, sed laŭtan ŝuŝan (la unua estas el "La batalo de'l vivo", tre frua teksto, kaj la dua el "Fabeloj de Andersen III", tre malfrua):

> la krakado de la teleroj kaj pladoj, la muĝado de la patoj, la skuiĝado de la kaseroloj
>   la kolo de botelo, kiu ekmuĝis, kiam la korko brue elsaltis

Ŝajnas al mi, ke ni origine havis okazon kiel ĉe la prepozicio *ĉe*: Latinida formo (franca *chez*), slava signifo (rusa *y*). Eble jam en la tempo de Zamenhof**, trompate de la ekstera formo kaj pro la simila uzo rilate venton (kiu povas ja eligi diversajn sonojn), la parolantoj ŝanĝis la kvaliton de la sono priskribata per *muĝi* de alta, sibla al malalta, brua.

Ĉar la Akademiaj korektoj estas oficialaj, oni devas nun uzi la vorton laŭ tiu pli nova signifo, la pli frua signifo estas arkaika.

*Oni povus obĵeti, ke la radiko SIBL' ja ekzistas jam en la UV. Efektive ankaŭ ĝi havas tie la rusan tradukon шипeть, sed kun indiko "rilate elparolon". Z uzis la verbon *sibli* ne por la laŭta sono ekz. de serpentoj, sed por la tre alta, mallaŭta de musoj, flugantaj sagoj/kugloj.

**Sed komparu ĉi tiun citaĵon el "Ĉu li", kiu groteske sonas laŭ la hodiaŭa signifo:

> Jes, muĝis Reĝino per siblanta apenaŭ distingebla voĉo

Comment: +1 pro la vidpunkto laŭ oficialeco. Tamen, ĉu vere _vento_ ne devus esti aldonita almenaŭ al la [germana](http://www.fidazi.info/neuer_auftritt/lyrik1/texte/text_song10.htm) kaj [rusa](https://www.stihi.ru/2016/08/31/6224) klarigoj? La polan mi ne konas, do mi ne povas juĝi pri _w kominie huczał wiatr_ “en la kameno muĝis vento” (?) guglebla en libro pri Auschwitz... Mi tamen korektis mian respondon pri vento en la komunaĵo de la signifaroj de la UV-difinoj.

Comment: Ĉu vi konsentas, ke tiu groteske muĝanta reĝino nunligve estus _grumblanta?_ (alia signifo de шипеть, cetere.)

Comment: 1. Jes, mi aldonu venton ĉe la germana (_brausen_, sed ne _brüllen_) kaj pola (tion mi ne konas, _huk_ ĉiam ŝajnis al mi ĉiam io laŭta, subita, sed mi ne estas denaska parolanto), pri la rusa mi ne kompetentas.
2. Rilate la reĝinon, mi ne tute scias, kion mi nun dirus, ĉar ni ja havas kaŭzon dubi, ĉu ni (kaj Valienne ;-)) vere bona komprenas _muĝi_.

Answer (score 2):

Mi fakte ne komprenas la problemon. "Muĝi" estas speco de profunda ĝem-sono kiel tiu de bovino aŭ la maro. Ĉiuj difinioj kaj tiuj longaj klarigoj subtenas tiun ideon.

Answer (score 1):

Estas interese, ke la granda estimata esperanto-rusa vortaro de Boris Kondratjev ([rueo.ru](http://rueo.ru)) nuntempe tute ne atribuas signifon "шипеть" (*"sibli"*) al la vorto. Laŭ ĝi, ***"muĝi"*** (*"реветь"*, *"мычать"*) esprimas ĝuste sonojn de bovo, ŝtormo, akvofalo, homamaso ktp.